# Trouble centering image class tag

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble getting the image on this page:

http://www.cultcitychi.com/event/interpol-the-riv/

to respond to the selector below (Im trying to center it):

`.tribe-events-event-image.center{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}`

Have I incorrectly inspected the HTML?

Comment: .single-tribe_events .tribe-events-event-image have attribute text-align:left which is overridden. Kindly change text-align: left to center or just remove this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your css class (.single-tribe_events .tribe-events-event-image --  `text-align:left` with `text-align:center`) with  the below

**CSS**

```
.single-tribe_events .tribe-events-event-image{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.single-tribe_events .tribe-events-event-image {
margin-bottom: 1.25em;
text-align: left;
}
```

remove `text-align:left` from this code.

Answer (score 0):

center can use :

```
margin:0 auto;
```